# Como pegar o valor <td> de uma table estando em outra table?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

Eu tenho uma table com checkboxs para marcar e desmarcar as linhas da tabela.

Acontece que eu tenho uma outra tabela, que é um resumo totalizador das contas.

Quero que toda a vez que o usuário marcar um checkbox, o Jquery encontre na outra tabela a td correspondente e faça a operação de soma ou subtração na td correta.

Como eu pego os valores corretos? Do jeito que fiz não retorna...

TABELA RESUMO:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML DA TABELA GERADA COM PHP:

```html
<div class="col-md-8">
            <table class="table table-striped table-responsive" id="tabResumo">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th>DRE</th>
                            <th>Meta Mensal</th>
                            <th>Total Pago</th>
                            <th>Total Lançado</th>
                            <th>Saldo</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($previsaoMes as $linha): ?>
                        <?php $saldo = $linha['valor_previsto'] - ($linha['valor_pago'] + $linha['lancado']) ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="<?php echo $linha['nomeDRE'] ?>"><?= $linha['nomeDRE'] ?></td>
                            <td class="text-right"><?= number_format($linha['valor_previsto'], 2, ',', '.') ?></td>
                            <td class="text-right"><?= number_format($linha['valor_pago'], 2, ',', '.') ?></td>
                            <td class="text-right"><?= number_format($linha['lancado'], 2, ',', '.') ?></td>
                            <td class="text-right"><?= number_format($saldo, 2, ',', '.') ?></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <?php endforeach ?>    
                    </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

A OUTRA TABELA ONDE CLICO NO CHECKBOX:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML DESTA 2ª TABELA:

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
                    <?php if (count($lista) > 0): ?>
                        <table id="tabela" class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>DRE</th>
                                    <th>Despesa</th>
                                    <!-- <th>#</th> -->
                                    <th>Vencimento</th>
                                    <th>Prorrogação</th>
                                    <th class="text-right">Valor</th>
                                    <th>Parcela</th>
                                    <th>Devedora</th>
                                    <th>Observação</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Conf</th>
                                    <th>Prorrogar</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php foreach ($lista as $linha): ?>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td><?= $linha['nomeDRE'] ?></td>
                                        <td><?= $linha['nomeFornecedor'] ?></td>
                                        <!-- <td><?= $linha['parcela_id'] ?></td> -->
                                        <td><?= implode("/", array_reverse(explode("-", trim($linha['data_vencimento'])))); ?></td>
                                        <td><?= implode("/", array_reverse(explode("-", trim($linha['data_prorrogacao'])))); ?></td>
                                        <td class="text-right monetary"><?= number_format($linha['valor_pagar'], 2, ',', '.') ?></td>
                                        <td class="text-center"><?= $linha['numero_parcela']."/". $linha['total_parcela'] ?></td>
                                        <td><?= $linha['nomeEmpresaDevedora'] ?></td>
                                        <td><?= $linha['observacao'] ?></td>
                                        <!--  <td><span <?php echo ($linha["status"] == 'SOLICITAR')? 
                                                'class="label label-primary"':'class="label label-default"'?>>
                                                <?php echo $linha["status"];?>
                                            </span></td> -->
                                        <td class="text-center">
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" id="<?= $linha['parcela_id'] ?>" value="<?= $linha['parcela_id'] ?>" checked>
                                                    <span class="form-check-sign">
                                                        <span class="check"></span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="text-center">
                                            <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Prorrogar data">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-fab btn-fab-mini js-modalData" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalData" onclick="pegarIdProrrogacao(<?php echo $linha['parcela_id'];?>)" aria-label="Left Align">
                                                    <i class="material-icons">date_range</i>
                                                </button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php endforeach ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                            <strong>ATENÇÃO!</strong> Nenhuma conta encontrada.
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </div>
```

SCRIPT QUE PEGA O CLIQUE NO CHECKBOX DA 2ª TABELA. MAS O VALOR VEM EM BRANCO E O VALOR ESPERADO ERA 328.964,69. OS OUTROS CÁLCULOS ESTÃO FUNCIONANDO, POIS EU TENHO CARDS QUE TOTALIZAM:

```js
<script>
    $(':checkbox').click(function() {
        var total = 0;
        var saldo = 0;
        var total_orcado = 0;
        var total_pago = 0;
        var total_pagar = 0;
        
        var valor = parseFloat($(this)      // Representa o elemento clicado (checkbox)
                            .closest('tr')  // Encontra o elemento pai do seletor mais próximo
                            .find('td')     // Encontra o elemento do seletor (todos os tds)
                            .eq(4)          // pega o quinto (contagem do eq inicia em 0)
                            .text()         // Retorna o texto do elemento
                            .split('.')
                            .join('')
                            .replace(',','.'));    

        // COMO EXEMPLO, AQUI ESTOU TENTANDO PEGAR O VALOR DO SALDO DO INVESTIMENTO
        var valor2 = $('#tabResumo').parent().find("INVESTIMENTO").eq(4).text();

        // AQUI EU MOSTRO O VALOR RETORNADO COM O ALERT, MAS VEM EM BRANCO
        alert("VALOR SALDO RESUMO DE INVESTIMENTO: "+valor2);
        
        total = parseFloat($('#total_a_pagar').val().split('.').join('').replace(',','.'));
            
        saldo = parseFloat($('#saldo').val().split('.').join('').replace(',','.'));

        //Chama a função com click em qualquer checkbox
        //Se o checkbox for marcado ele soma. Se não, subtrai.
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            saldo += valor;
            total += valor;
        } else {
            saldo -= valor;
            total -= valor;
        }
        //Atribui o valor ao input
        $('#total_a_pagar').val(total.toLocaleString('pt-br', {minimumFractionDigits: 2})) || 0;
        $('#saldo').val(saldo.toLocaleString('pt-br', {minimumFractionDigits: 2})) || 0;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Observações sobre o seu código:

```
$('#tabResumo').parent().find("INVESTIMENTO").eq(4).text();
```

Você está tentando encontrar um elemento html de nome "INVESTIMENTO", ou seja . O que não existe. O mais provável é que você esteja procurando uma classe com esse nome, mas não encontrei essa palavra no seu código, não sei se você está colocando via PHP. Se for mesmo uma classe vc precisa usar dessa forma:

```
$('#tabResumo').parent().find(".INVESTIMENTO").eq(4).text();
```

Uma dica que eu te daria é: trabalhe com identificadores em ambas as tabelas para facilitar os relacionamentos e encontrar o valor que você precisa.

Um exemplo seria atribuir a classe "valor" na celula que contem os valores e usar um seletor jquery mais simples para encontrá-la.

Também existem formas muito mais seguras e consistentes de achar um valor ao invés do .eq()

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, vou pesquisar. Abs